# Why clojure's vector function definition is so verbose?

Tags: clojure

I'm really curious to see why vector's implementation is so verbose? What's the reason it can't just do `[]`, `[a]` and `[a & args]`?

Here is what I get from `clj-1.4.0`.

```
=> (source vector)
(defn vector
  "Creates a new vector containing the args."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  ([] [])
  ([a] [a])
  ([a b] [a b])
  ([a b c] [a b c])
  ([a b c d] [a b c d])
  ([a b c d & args]
     (. clojure.lang.LazilyPersistentVector (create (cons a (cons b (cons c (cons d args))))))))
nil
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328359/why-does-vector-implementation-have-multiple-cases

Answer (score 10):

The first few cases have direct calls to make them faster because they are the most commonly called. The rare cases where it is called with many arguments may require more calls and hence more time, but this keeps the common cases concise. **It was a deliberate speed, verbosity tradeoff**. It also makes the use of the function clear from looking at the argument list without cluttering people's IDEs with a huge list of arities.

Most of Clojure's core functions have similar signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Further to [@ArthurUlfeldt's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11570880/1562315).

There is a case for having *reference implementations* for the core functions, say in namespace `clojure.core.reference`. These would be shorter, hence clearer, though slower than their standard counterparts. The testing regime would make sure that they produced the same results.

For example, the reference implementation for `vector` could be

```
(ns clojure.core.reference)

(defn vector
  "Creates a new vector containing the args."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [& args]
  (. clojure.lang.LazilyPersistentVector (create args)))
```

In addition to testing the various optimisations and speed-ups employed by the core library, the reference implementations would be first port of call for those trying to understand what the code does.